# smallest possible value of $\alpha$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $(x^3+\alpha x^2+2x-5)^{19}(x^2+\beta x-41)^8(x^4-x^3+x-7)^6=x^{97}+391x^{96}+95x^{95}+a_{94}x^{94}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}$ be an identity.where $\alpha,\beta,a_{95},a_{94},\cdots\cdots,a_{1},a_{0}$ are integers. If $\alpha+\beta<10.$ Then the possible value of $\alpha$ is

what i try

put $x=0,$ Then $(-5)^{19}\cdot (-41)^{8}\cdot (-7)^6=a_{0}$

put $x=1,$ Then $$(\alpha-2)^{19}\cdot (\beta-40)^8\cdot (-6)^6=1+391+95+a_{94}+\cdots \cdots +a_{1}+a_{0}$$

How do i solve it Help me please Thanks

Comment: You have to compare coefficients of $x^{96}$ and $x^{95}$, Calculating the coeff of $x^{95}$ is a tiresome slog.

Comment: Are you sure the coefficient of $x^{95}$ is not $a_{95}$; you mention $a_{95}$ in "where ...".

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The sum of the roots is $-391=-19\alpha-8\beta+6$.

*Solution:*
The integer solutions of the equation above are given by $\alpha = 8 n + 7$, $\beta = 33 - 19 n$, with $n \in \mathbb Z$. Requiring that $\alpha+\beta<10$ gives $n\ge3$. Therefore, the smallest possible value of $\alpha$ comes from $n=3$ and so is $\alpha=31$.

(I think the coefficient of $x^{95}$ is $a_{95}$, not $95$.)

Comment: Great. Except it gives the wrong coefficient of $x^{95}$. Check with WolframAlpha.

Comment: Many values of $\alpha,\beta$ give the right coefficient of $x^{96}$ and satisfy $\alpha+\beta<10$. You need one which also gives the right coefficient of $x^{95}$

Comment: @almagest, there are no integer solutions then. See [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=171+a%5E2+%2B+8+%2819+a+-+6%29+b+-+114+a+%2B+28+b%5E2+-+275%3D95%2C+19+a+%2B+8+b+-+6%3D391). I think $95$ is $a_{95}$.